# Altering stored procedure that ALTERs a table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have a procedure that does the following in order

1. Create table with a single column
2. Inserts data in the table
3. Adds more columns to the table

After the first execution of the SP, the table already exists. Hence, if I make changes in the SP and try to save it, it throws an error at the Insert step saying 
"Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Is there any way to disable this 'check' and somehow update the SP without having to drop the table?

EDIT: This SP is supposed to run only once a year, to generate a report. Nobody looks at it until next year. Actually, there is a set of 5-6 stored procedures that generates all the tables (about 25) which are then used to make a report. So, when a change is made in the SP, the tables are dropped and all the SP are run once again.

EXAMPLE:

```
CREATE proc sp_temp
AS

BEGIN
BEGIN TRY DROP TABLE TX END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH
CREATE TABLE TX (ID INT)

DECLARE @I INT =0
WHILE (@I<=10)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TX VALUES (@I)
    SET @I += 1
END

ALTER TABLE TX ADD COL1 VARCHAR(10)

INSERT INTO TX VALUES  (11, 'SOME TEXT');

END
```

EDIT2: Table is dropped before creation. 
But now my question is: SSMS identifies the error ie. mismatch in number of columns and number of values supplied but why can't it see that the table is dropped?

Comment: What is the sense of this. Are you expecting that stored proc will execute only once? Then why to use stored proc?

Comment: Please post your code. You must use IF statement to prevent re-create table

Comment: Smells like bad design

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited markdown (to simple blockquotes) of error, because now it can be better distinguished of other text.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: ^Thanks. Will note that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_temp]
AS
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE TX (ID INT)

    DECLARE @I INT =0

    WHILE (@I<=10)
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO TX(ID) VALUES (@I)
        SET @I += 1

    END

    ALTER TABLE TX ADD COL1 VARCHAR(10)
    INSERT INTO TX VALUES  (11, 'SOME TEXT');

END
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is "no". If you really must do it this way, then I suggest using dynamic SQL, and executing it.

This definitely sounds like poor design.